# How to configure a task to run it multiple times in gradle

Tags: gradle

I need to run jsonSchema2Pojo multiple times for different file sources and target packages. Under each folder it has more than one json files.

```
task 1 {
    jsonSchema2Pojo {
     Source = files(“src/main/resource/1”)
     targetPackage = “com.Test.employee ”

---
task 2 {
    jsonSchema2Pojo {
    Source = files (“src/main/resource/2”)
    targetPackage = “com.Test2.department”
  }
}
```

It only generate Java class  for the first task

Comment: A Gradle task can only run once per build. You'll have to create two tasks that can have the same type, but with different names. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:defining_tasks

Comment: I am using grade 7.1 and am getting "Could not find method register () for arguments [task 2 , task ':task1' , build_1xdm7....] on tsk set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.